# PI camera is not working

Tags: pi-4, camera, raspicam, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

Dear Raspberry Pi Community,

I am reaching out to seek insights into an issue I've encountered with the Raspberry Pi camera across three Raspberry Pi 4 (4GB) units, one of which was just recently acquired. Despite having an assortment of four distinct Pi cameras and six different ribbon connectors at my disposal, I've been unable to establish a consistent connection. On rare occasions, the camera has functioned as expected, but this behavior is short-lived, often ceasing after a system reboot.

Troubleshooting Steps Undertaken:

Configuration Adjustments: Modified config.txt settings, experimenting with both camera_auto_detect=1 and start_x=1.

Interface Activation: Ensured the camera and relevant interfaces were enabled via raspi-config.

Fresh OS Installations: Conducted multiple fresh installations of the Raspberry Pi OS.

System Updates: Performed system updates and full upgrades to ensure all software components were up-to-date.

Command-Line Configurations: Executed commands sudo usermod -a -G video pi and sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2 to ensure proper permissions and module loading.

Power Supply Verification: Tested with several official Raspberry Pi power adapters to rule out power-related inconsistencies.

Camera Detection: Consistently received supported=1 detected=1, libcamera interfaces=0 upon running vcgencmd get_camera.

Despite these extensive troubleshooting efforts, the issue persists. Given that I've observed this behavior across brand-new hardware components, including both the Raspberry Pi unit and the camera module, I am inclined to believe this may not be a hardware-related anomaly.